# How to add a class to element in Jquery and then trigger event based on that class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code that programatically adds a class to an element on document ready. The issue i am having is how to then listen for elements with that class being clicked.

```
<li><a href="#" id="btnDeleteGroup" class="disabled">Delete Node</a></li>

$(document).ready(function () {

  $('a.deleteGroup').click(function (e) {
    alert("deleteGroup"); 
  });

  $('#btnDeleteGroup').removeClass("disabled");
  $('#btnDeleteGroup').addClass("deleteGroup");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).on('click', 'a.deleteGroup', (function (e) {
    alert("deleteGroup"); 
  });

  $('#btnDeleteGroup').removeClass("disabled");
  $('#btnDeleteGroup').addClass("deleteGroup");

});
```

this binds the event to the document and then "listens" for you selector. Prefereably bind it to something more specific than the `document` for a performance increase, i.e. the `a` tags container.

Just to explain if you bind it to the document it will "listen" to every click event that happens on the document and then say "does this match my selector". If you bind it to the container it only catches click events on that container, so it has to deal with less requests and is thus more efficient.

Also `on` was introduced in Jquery 1.7, if your using an older version their are several less efficient versions of this such as [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). If your using 1.7 or newer though use `on`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click", "a.deleteGroup", function (e) {
  alert("deleteGroup"); 
});
```

Also it is better to bind event not to document but to some parent element of that link.

Comment: thanks, would you mind expanding on your comment about not binding the event to the parent? --Never mind I see Liam has done that below :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot listen on elements that are added AFTER the listener has been bound. To fix your issue, you need only re-order your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btnDeleteGroup').removeClass("disabled");
  $('#btnDeleteGroup').addClass("deleteGroup");

  $('a.deleteGroup').click(function(e) {
    alert("deleteGroup"); 
  });

});
```

Cheers,

Terence

Comment: Thanks terence, but this was trimmed down code, the class is actually added during another event which I didnt display here. thanks for help anyway.